# Вызов метода из родительского класса с переопределением метода

Tags: java, ооп

Задача:

Посчитать дистанцию для класса `Car` , и дистанцию для класса `JamesBondCar`.

Ожидаемые значения: 
для класса `Car` - 120, для класса `JamesBondCar` - 360.

Реальный результат в обоих случаях выводит 120, т.е игнорирует арифметическое действие в методе drive -  `distance = howlong * 180;`

И вроде бы, игнорирует вообще весь метод в классе `JamesBondCar`, а выполняет только метод из родительского класса.
А, также не включается тело метода start в классе - `JamesBondCar`.

Поиски решения - Пробовал override использовать и super.method. Присваивал другой вид переменной.

Жду любой информации - прямой ответ, ссылки, книги.

P.S Только начал освоение языке. Благодарю за помощь.

```
  public class Car{
            int distance;

            public void start(){
                System.out.println("Car is starting now");
            }

            public void stop(){

                System.out.println("Car is stopped now");
            }

            public int drive(int howlong){
                distance = howlong*60; //time * speed
                return distance;
            }


        }

    public class JamesBondCar extends Car{


        public void start(){
            System.out.println("I'm James Bond!");

        }

        public int drive(int howlong){
            distance = howlong * 180;

            return distance;
        }

    }
```

Вызываю классом:

```
public class CarOwner{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int distance;


        Car myCar = new Car();

        myCar.start();

        myCar.stop();

        distance = myCar.drive(2);
        System.out.println("My distance is " + distance + " now.");

        Car myBondCar = new Car();
        myBondCar.start();
        myBondCar.stop();
        distance = myBondCar.drive(2);
        System.out.println("I'm Bond, James Bond." + " And "+ "I have " + distance + " distance");


    }
}
```

Comment: Car myBondCar = new Car(); ну так вы и создавайте может new JamesBondCar()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В обоих случаях вы создаете объект родительского класса `Car`, поэтому и итог соответствующий.
Просто замените

```
Car myBondCar = new Car();
```

на

```
Car myBondCar = new JamesBondCar ();
```

Comment: Встречный вопрос к вам, какая разница создания объекта: JamesBondCar myBondCar = new JamesBondCar(); и вашим вариантом. Знаю что Car(в вашем случае) или JamesBondCar в начале строки - играют роль нового типа переменной

Comment: Тут дружище самые основы наследования надо понимать. Преподаватель из меня так себе, лучше посмотреть чтонибудь типо этого: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/extends.php . Но если кратко: слева указывается то, что можно записать в эту переменную и как ее будут воспринимать, справа то что на самом деле туда записывается.

Comment: Другими словами указав слева Car мы можем записать туда объект этого класа или любого дочернего, но при этом будут доступны только те методы, которые были определены в классе Car (если мы в JamesBondCar добавим еще один метод, которого нет в классе Car, его не будет видно). В свою же очередь при записи в переменную объекта Car, он будет давать результаты как Car, а если записать JamesBondCar, то и результат будет соответствующий этому классу.